# Map an activerecord array to avoid that two item with the same attribute are in a sequential position

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue to solve.

I have an array of elements, and on each element I can call the method '`content.sponsored?`' that return me `true` or `false`.

The items that return `true` are 2/3 every 20 elements and they are always in the first position.

I need to map this array to avoid consecutive '`true`'.

For example

```
contents = [
  { id: 1, sponsored: true },
  { id: 2, sponsored: true },
  { id: 3, sponsored: false },
  { id: 4, sponsored: false },
  { id: 5, sponsored: false },
  { id: 6, sponsored: false }...
]
```

I need

```
contents = [
  { id: 1, sponsored: true },
  { id: 2, sponsored: false },
  { id: 3, sponsored: true },
  { id: 4, sponsored: false },
  { id: 5, sponsored: false },
  { id: 6, sponsored: false }...
]
```

Which is the most efficient way to map these elements?

Comment: modified_contents = contents.each_with_index.map do |content, index|
  # Check if the current element and the next one both have 'sponsored' as true
  if content[:sponsored] && contents[index + 1]&.fetch(:sponsored, false)
    # If yes, set the 'sponsored' attribute of the current element to false
    { id: content[:id], sponsored: false }
  else
    # Otherwise, keep the original element
    content
  end
end

puts modified_contents.inspect

Comment: Should the other of the `id` values in the second example change too? Do you need to avoid two consecutive `true` values at all cost? Or would a random order with a low probability of repeating `true` values be enough?